# Yii2: Multiple Environment Setup on same code base

Tags: yii2, environment-variables, yii2-advanced-app

I'm trying to run the same code base on same server but different environment setup, what I'm trying to achieve is very simple:
If user goes to : https://server/app : This loads the production environment
If users goes to : https://server/app-test : this load the development environment, the only thing I will need to load different is the database connection.

Is there any possible way of doing that?

Thanks

Comment: you have two separated  app directories?    one in /server/app and one in /server/app-test ?

Comment: @scaisEdge No i want to use the same code base (same folder) but different entry script, the entry script will only load a different database connection.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-configurations.html or https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/structure-environments.md. You have couple of options - 1. define environment-dependent variable `YII_ENV`, 2. load config specific file.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are having two different directories, if this is so, use the two different connections on both the applications.

Or

I think you are trying to achieve the following:

One Application and different database connections. If this is right, proceed with the following steps:

1. Create a database connection, say db.php  in your config directory

   ```
    <?php
   return [
      'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
      'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname',
      'username' => 'user',
      'password' => 'password',
      'charset' => 'utf8',
   ];
   ?>
   ```
2. Call the file db2.php in your web.php file, under the components section:

   ```
     'db2' => require(__DIR__ . '/db2.php'),
   ```
3. Wherever you want to use this database connection, override the default database connection with the db2 connection :

   ```
   class X extends ActiveRecord {

   public static function getDb() {
       return Yii::$app->get('db2'); // second database
   }

   public $ids;
   /**
    * @inheritdoc
    */
   public static function tableName() {
       return 'dbName';
   }

   /**
    * @inheritdoc
    */
   public function rules() {
       return [
          // Rules as per your Database
       ];
   }

   /**
    * @inheritdoc
    */
   public function attributeLabels() {
       return [
           'id' => 'ID',
       ];
   }
   }
   ```

Note that I have used this connection in the X model.

Comment: OP want's to use one directory app with 2 diffrent connections, not depending on overriding function in `ActiveRecord` class.